# Strings act weirdly when reading them from a file with the java.util.Scanner and using linebreaks as delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I try to read data from a file using the `java.util.Scanner`. When I try to use `\n` as a delimiter, then the resulting Strings react weirdly when I try to add more text to them.

I have a file called "test.txt" and try to read data from it. I then want to add more text to each String, similar to how this would print `Hello World!`:

```
String helloWorld = "Hello "+"World!";
System.out.println(helloWorld);.
```

I tried combining data with `+`, I tried `+=` and I tried `String.concat()`, this has worked for me before and usually still works.

I also tried to use different delimiters, or no delimiter at all, both of those work as I expect, but I need the Strings to be separated at line breaks.

The `test.txt` file for the minimal reproducible example contains this text (there is a space at the end of each line):

> zero:
>   one:
>   two:
>   three:

```
void minimalReproducibleExample() throws Exception {  //May throw an exception if the test.txt file can't be found

    String[] data = new String[4];

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("test.txt");
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\n");

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        data[i] = scanner.next();     //read the next line
        data[i] += i;                 //add a number at the end of the String
        System.out.println(data[i]);  //print the String with the number
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

I expect this code to print out these lines:

> zero: 0
>   one: 1
>   two: 2
>   three: 3

I get this output instead:

> 0ero:
>   1ne:
>   2wo:
>   three: 3

Why do I not get the expected output when using `\n` as a delimiter?

Comment: Are you using Windows or MacOS? What is the end of line sequence for `test.txt`, is it Linux `\n` or something else?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I use Windows 10, I believe build 1607. I have so far always used `\n` for linebreaks and never had any problems.

Comment: I have run ur code in Linux, it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `test.txt` is most likely using Windows [end of line representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) `\r\n` which results in [carriage return `\r`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) still being present in the `String` after it's read.

Ensure that `test.txt` is using `\n` as line delimtier or use Windows `\r\n` in `Scanner.useDelimiter()`.

Comment: I will try that in a bit

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with a wrong delimiter. If you use Windows 10, the new line separator is `\r\n`.

Just to be platform-independent use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of hardcoded `\n`.